# How do I configure module name when WebEssentials generates Typescript Intellisense file?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I've just discovered that, with WebEssentials 2013 I can right-click a CS file and choose Web Essentials->Create Typescript Intellisense File.

At the moment, all the generated interfaces are put in module "server". How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great question (where I didn't know the answer for) so I searched in the code from Web Essentials and yes this is possible! You need to do the following:

Create a new .cs file with the following code (don't do It in the same file you are generating definitions from or somehow it will throw an error).

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
sealed class TypeScriptModuleAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string moduleName;
    public TypeScriptModuleAttribute(string moduleName)
    {
        this.moduleName = moduleName;
    }
}
```

Now apply it to a class:

```
[TypeScriptModule("foo")]
public class TestClass
{
    <snip>
}
```

It will generate something like this:

```
declare module foo {
    interface TestClass {
    }
}
```

If you are interested, you can find the code where Web Essentials does this here: [link](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/a2c9774737e37a3288a4790e0ee5a2af35f262ba/EditorExtensions/Misc/CodeGeneration/IntellisenseParser.cs#L213) and the code for writing the file here: [link2](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/237e3ca3eef15ca47d3ffaf027397c46cc79aa3e/EditorExtensions/Misc/CodeGeneration/IntellisenseWriter.cs#L161)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for going the extra mile!

Comment: Hi Dick: Here's a related question, if you fancy another challenge: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25325553/1727