# How do I get interface inheritance working correctly when generating WebEssentials Typescript Intellisense?

Tags: typescript, web-essentials

I have two classes:

```
[TypeScriptModule("commands")]
public class ClientCommand : VoidCommand
{
    public string CommandType { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[TypeScriptModule("commands")]
public class PublishEvent : ClientCommand
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I use the WebEssentials "Create Typescript Intellisense file" command on these files, the one generated for PublishEvent doesn't include an "extends ClientCommand" expression.

A quick scan of the [WebEssentials code](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/a2c9774737e37a3288a4790e0ee5a2af35f262ba/EditorExtensions/Misc/CodeGeneration/IntellisenseParser.cs#L213) suggests that this ought to work, but I'm obviously missing something. Any ideas what?

Comment: It seems to work for me because it generates "interface PublishEvent extends ClientCommand", is all the code in the same file or different files?

Comment: Code is in different files. But it doesn't work even if they are both in the same file.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.3 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the latest version of WebEssentials. This feature didn't work in WebEssentials 2.0, but does work without any further changes need in version 2.3